# PHP - with and clone instead of constructor

Tags: php, oop

I have seen code like the following a few times and cannot think what the reasonsing is:

```
public function withParameter($parameter)
{
    $clone = clone $this;
    $clone->parameter = $parameter;

    return $clone;
}
```

Also similar things:

```
public static function fromString(string $parameter)
{
    return new StringValueClass($parameter);
}
```

Why have a static function like this instead of just use the constructor?

Comment: It would help to see more context on the `withParameter()` to see how it's used. Regarding the static function, again more context from the class is needed but sometimes the real constructor is made private and instead the class may offer several different methods of instantiating one given different types of input params, implemented as static creator methods.

Comment: The first case looks like it's forcing the class to behave like a value type meaning you can freely call functions and get new instances of the class but maintain the original one if you need it. The second one depends on context but it does look like it's just providing a more expressive way to create object instances.

Answer (score 2):

**Function 1:**

```
public function withParameter($parameter)
{
    $clone = clone $this;
    $clone->parameter = $parameter;
    return $clone;
}
```

This function is returning clone of current class object `$this` in which a parameter `$clone->parameter` is set. Here you can performed operation on object `$clone` which in return does not effect your current class object `$this`

**Function 2:**

```
public static function fromString(string $parameter)
{
    return new StringValueClass($parameter);
}
```

Here we are returning some other class object through this static function you can return an object but through `__construct` you can not, because does not `return` anything